# Does every object in JS have a toString() method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

[image]

[image]

If that is true, why this error happens? The `req.body` object is not `null` or `undefined` as the picture shows.

I use the `node-inspector` to debug my `express.js` app, this picture is taken in `Chrome Developer Tools`.

Express configuration:

`app.use(express.bodyParser())`

Thanks to your comments, now I found the `req.body` is `undefined`, but new question is how to make the `toString` works again? I want `req.body.toString()` to return string as below:

[image]

How to re-sign a proper `toString` method?

I tried `delete` the undefined `toString`, no good. See:

[image]

Comment: The method may have been removed. Check this out: `var foo = {}; foo.ToString(); foo.toString = undefined; foo.toString();`. Run this and see what happens.

Comment: Can you please expand the `__proto__` property(ies) and upload another screenshot?

Comment: Your addendum with `delete` is a bit of a red herring. In your example, `a` never had its own `toString` method; it was always inhered from its prototype. Thus, the `delete` has no effect, because `a` doesn't have a `toString` method (i.e., `a.hasOwnProperty("toString") is false).

Comment: I added another picture.

Comment: What does your Express configuration look like? Some elements like [bodyParser](http://expressjs.com/api.html#bodyParser) will change how `req.body` is handled.

Comment: Turns out the solution is not in the `Object` prototype, but probably lies in a custom `toString` directly on the instance itself. Could you *also* show `req.body.toString` (no parens to invoke it -- I want to see the console rendering of the function's code).

Comment: Oh, `req.body.toString` shows `undefined`! So how to re-sign a proper `toString` to it?

Comment: If a `toString` value is defined directly on your instance, `delete` is actually the answer here. Your prototype's `toString` function is "shadowed" by another value on the instance itself. By doing `delete req.body.toString` you blow away the `undefined` value and let the prototype's `toString` shine through. You could also do `Object.prototype.toString.call(req.body)` if you wanted to invoke it without `delete`ing the instance `toString`.

Comment: @apsillers The `delete` does works, but the `Object.prototype.toString.call(req.body)` works.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Does every object in JS have a toString() method?

No. Only those that inherit it from `Object.prototype` (as all normal objects do) or define it on its own (or inherit it from their custom prototype) do.

You can create such unusual objects by `Object.create(null)`. You also could give a plain object an own `toString` property that shadows the inherited one and is not a function (e.g. `{toString:0}`), but I guess that would've throw a distinct error.

In your case, it seems that the [querystring parser](https://github.com/visionmedia/node-querystring) used by `bodyParser()` does (did) indeed create objects without prototypes, to avoid mangling `.constructor.prototype` when such parameters were used. See [qs pullrequest #58](https://github.com/visionmedia/node-querystring/pull/58) and [express issue 1636: *Bodyparser not setting object.prototype?*](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/issues/1636) (suggesting an update).

> How to reassign a proper toString method?

You could just assign any function, like

```
req.body.toString = function() { return "Hi, I'm a request body"; };
```

but probably you want the standard one:

```
req.body.toString = Object.prototype.toString;
```

Other options would be redefining the prototype via the non-standard `__proto__` property (`req.body.__proto__ = Object.prototype`) or simply applying a standalone function on the object instead of making it a method, like `Object.prototype.toString.call(req.body)`.

Comment: The results of `toString()` can also vary depending on environment, so even if it's present it's worth keeping in mind that its output may be unreliable for certain functions.

Comment: +1, but note that `req.body` here seems to have an `Object` prototype, so there might be some more going on in the OP's particular case. Maybe this object delegates its `toString` to a non-`Object`-prototyped object?

Comment: @apsillers: Yeah, that's what I suspect as well. Maybe the request body's (custom) `toString` method does try to call `toString()` on some other object…

Comment: I added another picture, hope it can help make it more clear.