# object instanceof Object is false ,why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, instanceof

in express on node

`var query = request.query;`
print out the info of `query` below:
[image: console]
[image: result]

---

**add:**

on `mac`: `query instanceof Object` is true
but on `CentOS release 6.4 (Final)` : is false(images below)

**add again:**
node: `0.12.2`
express: `3.4.4`
OS: `CentOS release 6.4(Final)`

Comment: Can you do `console.log(query,__proto__ == Object.prototype)`?

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce this issue in both Express 3 and Express 4 and I am unable to. There must be something peculiar in your code. Please provide more of your code! Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at [Does every object in JS have a toString() method?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18640776/1048572)

Comment: Typically when `foo instanceof Object === false`, the `foo` was created in such a way that does not share `Object.prototype`. For example `var foo = Object.create(null);` will create an object with no (Object) prototype. This also means it has no built-in methods anymore. However, I cannot find `Object.create(null)` or similar being used in Express or in any of its dependencies for querystring parsing.

Comment: Additionally, re-assigning `foo.__proto__` to something other than `Object.prototype` will cause the `instanceof` check to return false.

Comment: @mscdex: No: `var foo = {}; var bar = {}; foo.__proto__ = bar; foo instanceof Object;`

Comment: @Bergi `console.log(query,__proto__ == Object.prototype)` true

Comment: @SKing7: Sorry, typo. I meant `console.log(query.__proto__ == Object.prototype)` which must not yield `true`

Comment: @Trott there are only the read operation on request.query

Comment: @Bergi yes, i find the typo, it return true

Comment: @SKing7: But then `query instanceof Object` must return `true` as well? (Or otherwise there's a serious issue somewhere)

Comment: @Bergi yes  it is strange.

Comment: Well, if `query.__proto__ == Object.prototype && !(query instanceof Object)`, then that means a) someone played with `.__proto__` b) someone played with `.prototype` c) your engine has a bug.

Comment: That may be the only place you do anything with `request.query` in your code, but there may be weirdness with the way `request` is handled, or there may be important middleware modifiying `request` before your middleware or any number of other things. Moreover, if there really is nothing else going on, then the code will be just a few lines and there's no reason not to show it. Without additional context, we are all wasting our time on this.

Answer (score 1):

This code displays `true` in both Express 3 and Express 4.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send(req.query instanceof Object);
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {

  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);

});
```

So this does not seem to be a problem that is generally (or at least not universally) present in Express.

Most likely thing I can think of is that somewhere in your code (or in a library/middleware you are using), `query.__proto__` is set to something that looks like an object but is not. Maybe something similar to this?:

```
var query = {};
query.__proto__ = null;
query.__proto__ = '{}';
console.log(query.__proto__); // {}
console.log(typeof query); // object
console.log(query instanceof Object); // false
```

Comment: Notice that `query.__proto__ = '{}';` does absolutely nothing (imo, it should `throw` in strict mode)

Comment: It does nothing good, but it does do one thing bad:  It causes a misleading message for `console.log(query.__proto__);`.  I put it there to generate log messages that are consistent with what the OP is reporting.

Comment: @Trott: Ah I see, it's no longer a setter there.