# Undefined JavaScript Object Constructor

Tags: javascript

I've been using the same JavaScript library I've built for years, and now I'm encountering errors with this function:

```
IsArray : function ()
{
    if (typeof arguments[0] == 'object')
    {
        var criterion = arguments[0].constructor.toString().match(/array/i);
        return (criterion != null);
    }

    return false;
}
```

There are times when it is called when the following error is thrown:

> TypeError: Cannot call method "toString" of undefined

I added the following prior to defining the **criterion** variable to remedy the issue:

```
if (arguments[0].constructor == null || arguments[0].constructor == undefined)
    return false;
```

However, I'd like to understand how or why this would happen. I don't know why a variable that has a type of 'object' would not have a constructor. I've never seen it prior to this issue. And what bothers me about this is this all started a few weeks after I updated another library function that checks for nulls and empty strings to try to filter out empty arrays (when comparing an empty array to an empty string, it was returning a match).

Comment: `null` is of type object with typeof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... As you may know, JavaScript is a bit surprising sometimes. With ES3, it was not easy at all to determine if an array was actually an array. So if you want to keep your legacy code, I think you should follow the great tips given by **Douglas Crockford** in *JavaScript: The Good Parts*.

> JavaScript does not have a good mechanism for distinguishing between
>   arrays and objects. We can work around that deficiency by defining our
>   own is_array function:

```
var is_array = function (value) {
  return value && typeof value === 'object' && value.constructor === Array;
};
```

> Unfortunately, it fails to identify arrays that were constructed in a
>   different window or frame. If we want to accurately detect those
>   foreign arrays, we have to work a little harder:

```
var is_array = function (value) {
  return Object.prototype.toString.apply(value) === '[object Array]';
};
```

Moreover, you should be very careful when you play with `null` because `Object.create(null)` creates an object without any prototype, `typeof null` returns **object** and `null == undefined` returns **true**...

With ES5, the best solution is to use `Array.isArray()`.

Comment: ES5 does have `Array.isArray`. It was only in the olden days that it was really hard.

Comment: Nice comment, thanks! You are right. For some reasons, my mind has mixed three specifications on this topic... I thought that `Array.isArray()` was part of ES6 like `Array.from()`, but it is part of ES5. The above code was useful in ES3 and older polyfills. I will edit my answer. :)

Comment: I had to test this, as I'm working with a server-side JavaScript engine, but it does the trick. My method had worked consistently for years, so I'm glad I can use this now. Odd thing, it worked with one array defined like ["","",""], and then failed a couple lines later with another similar array. So strange.

Comment: @Badacadabra Why would someone use Object.create(null)?

Answer (score 1):

Not all objects have a `.constructor` property, e.g. `Object.create(null)`, just like [not all objects have a `toString` method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18640776/1048572).

For your `IsArray` function, you should use the native [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) method, or its usual polyfill.